# how to get rank according to group and year of birth

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I have a table with gr_no, year_dob, family_id etc. etc.
I am trying to rank birth year according to family_id and am unable to generate the siblings_rank result.

```
+----------+--------------+-----------+
| gr_no    | year_dob     | family_id | siblings_rank
+----------+--------------+-----------+
|     1001 | 1992         |    95     |  1
|    10234 | 1995         |    95     |  2
|    10236 | 2004         |    96     |  1
|    15568 | 2006         |    96     |  2
|     1225 | 2004         |    92     |  1
+----------+--------------+-----------+
```

This query is working :

```
SET @prev := null;

SET @cnt := 1;

SELECT gr_no, gs_id, gf_id, year_dob, IF(@prev <> gf_id, @cnt := 1, @cnt := @cnt + 1) AS siblings_position, @prev := gf_id as previous_gf_id
FROM student_registered
ORDER BY gf_id, year_dob asc
```

This query is also working:

```
SELECT gr_no, gs_id, gf_id, year_dob, IF(@prev <> gf_id, @cnt := 1, @cnt := @cnt + 1) AS siblings_position, @prev := gf_id as previous_gf_id
FROM student_registered
JOIN (SELECT @prev := null) p
JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 1) c
ORDER BY gf_id, year_dob asc
```

............... I am unable to create view with these query?

or
If a procedure can update the student_registered column 'siblings_position' based on the queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use sql variables in the view

here is another way to get the same result using correlated subquery

```
SELECT gr_no, family_id,year_dob,
       ( select count(*) from Table1  T1
         where T1.family_id = T.family_id
         and T1.year_dob <= T.year_dob) as siblings_position
FROM Table1 T
ORDER BY family_id, year_dob asc
```

Comment: Total records are 6019 and this query   SELECT gr_no, gs_id, year_dob, gf_id,
       (select count(*) from student_registered T1
         where T1.gf_id = T.gf_id
         and T1.year_dob <= T.year_dob) as siblings_position
FROM student_registered T
ORDER BY gf_id, year_dob asc   is returning 25 results

Comment: @atif Naseem, the sub query won't restrict rows, the position might be coming as 25 , can u confirm? Try with out subquery and see ?

Comment: I resolved this by adding one more column "sibling_position" and store the data in it.... Your query is woking thank you so much radar but taking more than 9 seconds in view... : (